# How to not apply a css block?

Tags: css

I am a backend developer, I don't know anything about css, so my question can seems pretty dumb to you ...

A client noticed that there is a text that rewrite another one
[image]

I found that it's because this "class" or "proprety" (I don't know how to call it ) is defined :

```
.timeline-list .item.has-image h2 {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px; left: 15px; right: 15px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

How can I apply every other propriety of the class `timeline-list` but not this one ? (`timeline-list` is called in another part of the code where it is important to have this)

This is where I call the css :

```
    <ul class="list timeline-list">
        <li ng-repeat="nextItem in nextItems" class="item animated bounce-in-out vitesse-4 {{nextItem.css}}">
            <!-- <a href="#/content/poi/{{nextItem.id}}" nav-direction="forward"> -->
                <h2> {{nextItem.subtitle}} </h2>
                <div class="preview artBG">
                    <h3>{{nextItem.place}}</h3>
                    <h4>Dans {{nextItem.distanceFromPosition | number:2}} km</h4>
                </div>
            <!-- </a> -->
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks and sorry for my dumb question ...

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in fiddle or snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you've given, I would say that the issue is with the position:absolute; property. If you change it to relative does this fix your problem?

Comment: Yes it does but not as I would like. Problem 1 is that when I call the class timeline-list  from an other place, there is a display problem. Problem 2 is that other propriety like     top: 15px; left: 15px; right: 15px; still applies, so when my item has an image, there is a blank new line that appears here. So I just want to not call .timeline-list .item.has-image at all.

Comment: I can't quite work out what it is you're having an issue with. Could you recreate in a jsfiddle or link me to somewhere I can see the issue myself? You should also be able to remove the  `top: 15px; left: 15px; right: 15px;` properties too.

Comment: Sorry I can't do that, I am developing a very special app, it's a mobile app coded in angularJS and compiled with a framework called ionic so it's pretty difficult to share

Comment: @SamWillis Yes, if I remove them it works very well, but I still have my problem 1, that if I remove that another page of my app won't work as intented since it use this css class.

Comment: Can you create another class that you could target seperately? Could you do `<ul class="list timeline-list NEWCLASS">` and then do a new css rule for it as 
`.timeline-list.NEWCLASS .item.has-image h2    {position:relative; top:0; left:0; right:0;}`

Comment: Nice, this work fine. I have just a last issue, when my item got an image, I have a blank new line that shouldn't be here : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=822951Capturedcran20151023120543.png , got an idea why ?

Comment: Is it space where the image should be?
Also it could be padding or margin that is applied to either `class="preview artBG"` or the h3?